# Json parsing issue with Subarray elements in a array

Tags: json, parsing

I have a Json below which I am experiencing parse issues. I am not able to write sub array elements inside one array element. Need your help

```
    {
      "fulfillmentMessage": [{
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Element 1",
            "Element 2",
            "additionalCategory": [{
                "link": "",
                "followup_text": "Yes",
                "title": "Yes"
              },
              {
                "title": "No",
                "followup_text": "No",
                "link": ""
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
    }
```

For the above JSON, I am getting the below error

```
Error: Expecting Comma or ], not colon
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What issue you are facing and what you want to achieve? You can share your tried code too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @VivekJain, I have updated my json with the error which I am getting while I am formatting it. Hope it is clear now

Comment: find the edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the curly braces before "additionalCategory".
Try this.

```js
var json = {
  "fulfillmentMessage": [{
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "Element 1",
        "Element 2",
        {
          "additionalCategory": [{
              "link": "",
              "followup_text": "Yes",
              "title": "Yes"
            },
            {
              "title": "No",
              "followup_text": "No",
              "link": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
};
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Its working now. Thanks for your swift help.